# How to get parent object field values in a trigger

Tags: trigger, apex-email-service

I have created a trigger that send an email when some conditions are met in a task object. It is working fine but I need to get some field values from the parent object (an opportunity) in order to create the email content. How can I get this information from the parent object within the trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all of the associated WhatId so you can query for Opportunity and put it into a map.  You can then use the WhatId of your Task to fetch the appropriate object.  Also, you will want to make sure your Task is a child to an Opportunity and not just assuming like I show below:

```
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Task aTask: Trigger.new)
{
  oppIds.add(aTask.WhatId);
}

Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);

for (Task aTask: Trigger.new)
{
  Opportunity associatedOpp = oppMap.get(aTask.WhatId);
  if (associatedOpp != null)
  {
    //Do work with your Opp here
  }
}
```

Comment: just a little syntax error:  
instead of  
new Map<Id, Opportunity>{[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds];  
write  
*new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);*

Answer (score 1):

If the parent of a task is an opportunity, it will be in a field called "WhatId"

As you can see in the [documentation here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm), it is different (what and who) for different parent types.

So to answer your question, once you have your trigger set up you could/would use something like this to pull out all the opportunity data for the tasks in the trigger:

```
List<Id> theParents = new List<Id>();
for(Task thisTask : trigger.new)
{
    theParents.add(thisTask.WhatId);
}

List<Opportunity> theOpps = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :theParents];
```

And you could then add fields and deal with your data from there. I assume you have mechanisms already in place to make sure this trigger portion will only be firing on the Tasks of Opportunities?

If you have already taken steps to identify an opportunity record you wish to query, use something like:

```
Opportunity opp = [SELECT id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :t.WhatId];
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, the ID of the parent opportunity is in Task.WhatId but, how can I get the field values from that opportunity? Could you please, send some example code? I have: String Name = t.WhatId.Name; but the following error appears: Invalid foreign key relationship: Task.WhatId. Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, you can't do t.WhatId.Name - to access the fields you must put the t.WhatId into a SOQL query and load the opportunity data up. The code in my answer will get you a list of the opporunities, and dphils answer will help you get them into a map - which is more useful (but I figured you would be able to do this, I thought the question was just after the WhatId concept) I will update my answer with a single query if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema in Force.com IDE to get all needed relationships. In this case you must be sure that WhatId contains Opportunity Id. In other way you will have exception.

```
Select t.What.Description, t.What.Name, t.What.Id, t.WhatId From Task t
```

[image]